# Get response of a API request made using chrome-remote-interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-remote-debugging, taiko

I want to get the response data for the particular API call using chrome-remote-interface.
I am not sure how to print the response. I am able to get the APIs that are being called using the demo code available in their GitHub repo.

Mentioned a screenshot that I need from Chrome DevTools.

```
  const chromeLauncher = require("chrome-launcher");
  const CDP = require("chrome-remote-interface");
  const axios = require("axios");

  (async function () {
    async function launchChrome() {
      return await chromeLauncher.launch({
        chromeFlags: ["--no-first-run", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox"],
      });
    }

    const chrome = await launchChrome();
    const client = await CDP({
      port: chrome.port,
    });
    const { Network, Page } = client;
    await Page.enable();
    await Network.enable();
    await Page.navigate({ url: "[URL]" });
    await Page.loadEventFired();

    Network.requestWillBeSent((params) => {
      if (
        params.request.url ===
        "[URL]/rest/api/v1/ra/user?key=value&key=value"
      )
      {
        **Want to get the response for the API**
      }
    });
  })();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Network.getResponseBody`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-getResponseBody) to fetch the body of the response you want. See this minimal example (I changed the target URL because the one you used wasn't immediately fetched, at least for me):

```js
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');

(async function () {
    const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({
        chromeFlags: ['--no-first-run', '--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox'],
    });
    const client = await CDP({
        port: chrome.port,
    });

    const {Network, Page} = client;

    Network.responseReceived(async ({requestId, response}) => {
        if (response.url === 'https://geolocation.onetrust.com/cookieconsentpub/v1/geo/location') {
            const {body, base64Encoded} = await Network.getResponseBody({requestId});
            console.log(body, base64Encoded);
        }
    });

    await Network.enable();
    await Page.navigate({url: '[URL]'});
})();
```